# Cant return from a function to my html

Tags: php, mysqli

this is my html file **index.php**

```
<?php
    require_once(realpath(dirname(__FILE__)).'/../environments/include/ShowDataClass.php');
    $Show = new ShowDataClass();
    foreach ($Show->getAllUserPayments() as $key => $v) {
        if($v->date_reg != 0){
            $date_reg = $v->date_reg;
        }else{
            $date_reg = $Show->getInsertDate($v->metadata);
        }
        echo $date_reg;/*here the problem*/
    }
```

this is my **ShowDataClass.php**

```
class ShowDataClass extends DbClass{
    public function getInsertDate($id){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM metadata WHERE id = $id";
        $this->rs = $this->loadObjectList($query);
        if($this->rs[0]->prev_metadata == 0){
            $date = $this->rs[0]->date.' '.$this->rs[0]->time;
        }else{
            $this->getInsertDate($this->rs[0]->prev_metadata);
        }
        return strval($date);
    }
}
```

expected result **2017-09-18 19:22:49** but i got empty, `getInsertData($v->metadata)` all times send an id.
if i do an echo inside ShowDataClass in line 6 it return me the desired data.
could you please help me with this, need to use return but not working?

Comment: You are not doing anything with the value in the else block.

Comment: wich else you talking about?

Comment: This one: `else{ $this->getInsertDate($this->rs[0]->prev_metadata); }`. You call the `getInsertDate` method (which returns a value), but you don't use that returned value for anything.

Comment: oh man just went exausted and didnt see it thanks you so much!

Answer (score 2):

You have to return in the recursive call:

```
return $this->getInsertDate($this->rs[0]->prev_metadata);
```

Full code:

```
class ShowDataClass extends DbClass{
    public function getInsertDate($id){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM metadata WHERE id = $id";
        $this->rs = $this->loadObjectList($query);
        if($this->rs[0]->prev_metadata == 0){
            $date = $this->rs[0]->date.' '.$this->rs[0]->time;
        }else{
            return $this->getInsertDate($this->rs[0]->prev_metadata);
        }
        return strval($date);
    }
}
```